# Java Timestamp - How can I create a Timestamp with the date 23/09/2007?

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, date

How can I create a Timestamp with the date 23/09/2007?

Comment: Beware: `java.sql.Timestamp` is one of the terrible date-time classes that are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted years ago by the modern [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Answer (score 162, accepted):

By `Timestamp`, I presume you mean [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). You will notice that this class has a constructor that accepts a `long` argument. You can parse this using the `DateFormat` class:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("23/09/2007");
long time = date.getTime();
new Timestamp(time);
```

Comment: Normal ISO date format is yyyy-MM-dd, otherwise great!

Comment: new Timestamp(time); giving error that no constructor like this which take a long value :(

Comment: @Bhanu The docs show this does take a long value and appears to work correctly: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp(long)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 135):

What about this?

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2007-09-23 10:10:10.0");
```

Comment: Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2007-09-23 10:10:10.0"); is showing the valueOf method is undefined for the type Timestamp in jDK 7

Comment: new Timestamp(time); giving error that no constructor like this which take a string value :(

Comment: @Bhanu The constructor takes the unix time in milliseconds. Use the static method valueOf if you want to get a timestamp from a string.

Comment: This appears to be the best answer for the question.

Comment: The best answer has Date, which is deprecated, is bad practice to use it. This answers is better. Thank you

Answer (score 18):

What do you mean timestamp?  If you mean milliseconds since the Unix epoch:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2007, 9 - 1, 23);
long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

If you want an actual java.sql.Timestamp object:

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(millis);
```

Comment: WRONG and won't compile! Compile error: 09 is an octal number, but 9 is out of range for octals. Logic error: the month is 0-based, you will get OCTOBER 23th of 2007

Comment: I can't get a logic error if it doesn't compile. :)  Seriously, good catches, Carlos.  The octal I caught before but pasted wrong anyway. :(

Comment: Actually the Timestamp constructor is depricated rather you could use Timestamp.valueOf() method

Comment: @ShivaKomuravelly not all timestamp constructor are deprecated and atleast not which takes long as milliseconds, constructor which takes date as argument is deprecated

Comment: And there's a constant for that (instead of month = 9) : ``Calendar.SEPTEMBER``

Answer (score 14):

## tl;dr

```
java.sql.Timestamp.from (
    LocalDate.of ( 2007 , 9 , 23 )
             .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) )
             .toInstant()
)
```

## java.time

Let’s update this page by showing code using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

These new classes are inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. They supplant the notoriously troublesome old date-time classes bundled with early versions of Java.

In java.time, an `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC. A `ZonedDateTime` is an Instant adjusted into a time zone (`ZoneId`).

Time zone is crucial here. A date of `September 23, 2007` cannot be translated to a moment on the timeline without applying a time zone. Consider that a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal where it is still “yesterday”.

Also, a java.sql.Timestamp represents both a date and time-of-day. So we must inject a time-of-day to go along with the date. We assume you want the first moment of the day as the time-of-day. Note that this is not always the time `00:00:00.0` because of Daylight Saving Time and possibly other anomalies.

Note that unlike the old java.util.Date class, and unlike Joda-Time, the java.time types have a resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds. This matches the resolution of java.sql.Timestamp.

Note that the java.sql.Timestamp has a nasty habit of implicitly applying your JVM’s current default time zone to its date-time value when generating a string representation via its `toString` method. Here you see my `America/Los_Angeles` time zone applied. In contrast, the java.time classes are more sane, using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

```
LocalDate d = LocalDate.of ( 2007 , 9 , 23 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = d.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from ( instant ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "d: " + d + " = zdt: " + zdt + " = instant: " + instant + " = ts: " + ts );
```

When run.

> d: 2007-09-23 = zdt: 2007-09-23T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal] = instant: 2007-09-23T04:00:00Z = ts: 2007-09-22 21:00:00.0

By the way, as of JDBC 4.2, you can use the java.time types directly. No need for `java.sql.Timestamp`.

- `PreparedStatement.setObject`
- `ResultSet.getObject`

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I wonder how I can get OP or mods to mark your answer as the correct one. The accepted answer is so outdated.

Comment: Very nice, except for a typo. asStartOfDay() should be atStartOfDay().

Comment: @Tullochgorum Fixed. Thanks. FYI, on Stack Overflow, you are welcome to make such edits yourself, if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 6):

You could also do the following:

```
// untested
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 23);// I might have the wrong Calendar constant...
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 8);// -1 as month is zero-based
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2009);
Timestamp tstamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: WRONG: try a System.out.println of the result! You'll get something like: "2009-10-23 15:26:56.171"  Month is 0-based so 9 is October!

Comment: I knew one of those constants was zero-based, thanks.

Post updated.

Comment: Oh, and I did put 'untested' :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) the constructor which would accept year, month, and so on is deprecated. Instead you should use the Constructor which accepts a long.
You could use a [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) implementation to construct the date you want and access the time-representation as a long, for example with the [getTimeInMillis](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) method.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, also a solution with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) version 2.5 and its [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class:

```
new Timestamp(new DateTime(2007, 9, 23, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" )).getMillis())
```

Comment: Good answer, but you missed one *crucial* piece: **time zone**. If you omit a time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is applied to the `DateTime` object. That means your **results will vary** across various computers or configuration of the host OS or JVM settings. For predictable results, pass a time zone to that `DateTime` constructor. Pick the [proper time zone name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for your intention. For example, `DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" )` or `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

Comment: That code could be briefer. No need to convert to java.util.Date to get and pass milliseconds-since-[epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). Just ask the `DateTime` object for its milliseconds-since-epoch. Replace `.toDate().getTime()` with [`.getMillis()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis()).

Comment: @BasilBourque Depending on circumstances, you might want to leave out the timezone to have predictable results.  "In your current timezone" can be a perfectly reasonable and predictable result.  Why hardcode a timezone, or ask you users to manually set a timezone when their computer already has a timezone set?  Certainly i would be quite surprised if an application on my computer started outputing dates adjusted to America/Montreal timezone.

Comment: @dancarter Omitting the optional time zone leads to confusion. The omission raises the ambiguity of (a) did the programmer intend to rely on the implicit default or (b) did the programmer fail to consider time zone issues (as is all too common). If you do indeed want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, **say so explicitly** by calling `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` and passing the result as the optional argument. (By the way, ditto for `Locale.getDefault()`, same issue over ambiguity of optional arguments.)

Answer (score -1):

A more general answer would be to import `java.util.Date`, then when you need to set a `timestamp` equal to the current date, simply set it equal to `new Date()`.

Comment: because 
    ** Date("string"); ** is deprecated