# How to convert string date to Timestamp in java?

Tags: java

I want to convert string Date into Timestamp in java. The following coding i have written.I have declare the date for date1 is: 7-11-11 12:13:14.

```
SimpleDateFormat datetimeFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date lFromDate1 = datetimeFormatter1.parse(date1);
System.out.println("gpsdate :" + lFromDate1);
Timestamp fromTS1 = new Timestamp(lFromDate1.getTime());
```

I want to convert 7-11-11 12:13:14 this string date into timestamp. Now i got the output is 0007-11-11 00:13:14.000000 +05:30:00 but i want ( 7-11-11 12:13:14) this format Timestamp date. Can anyone please help me. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Timestamp - How can I create a Timestamp with the date 23/09/2007?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974973/java-timestamp-how-can-i-create-a-timestamp-with-the-date-23-09-2007)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

All you need to do is change the string within the [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) constructor to:
"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss".

Just use the appropriate letters to build the above string to match your input date.

Comment: I changed the SimpleDateFormat like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". Now i got a answer is 2007-11-11 12:13:14.000000 +05:30:00, the problem is i cant add this value into my database table. I want to display the date and time format is 2007-11-11 12:13:14. How to do this..?

Comment: Digging up an old post, but the included link is dead. For any one seeing this in the future, here's a working version: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: No quite right. The original Question's use of `7` as a value for a year is a serious problem.

Answer (score 18):

## tl;dr

```
java.sql.Timestamp                  
.valueOf(                           // Class-method parses SQL-style formatted date-time strings.
    "2007-11-11 12:13:14"
)                                   // Returns a `Timestamp` object.
.toInstant()                        // Converts from terrible legacy classes to modern *java.time* class.
```

## `java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf` parses SQL format

If you can use the full four digits for the year, your input string of `2007-11-11 12:13:14` would be in standard SQL format assuming this value is meant to be in UTC time zone.

The [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class has a [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) method to directly parse such strings.

```
String input = "2007-11-11 12:13:14" ;
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf( input ) ;
```

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, the java.time framework makes it easier to verify the results. The j.s.Timestamp class has a nasty habit of implicitly applying your JVM’s current default timestamp when generating a string representation via its [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString()) method. In contrast, the java.time classes by default use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

```
System.out.println( "Output: " + ts.toInstant().toString() );
```

Answer (score 6):

You can convert String to Timestamp:

```
String inDate = "01-01-1990"
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(((java.util.Date)df.parse(inDate)).getTime());
```

Answer (score 4):

Use capital `HH` to get hour of day format, instead of am/pm hours

Answer (score 4):

You can even try this.

```
   String date="09/08/1980";    // take a string  date
    Timestamp ts=null;  //declare timestamp
    Date d=new Date(date); // Intialize date with the string date
    if(d!=null){  // simple null check
        ts=new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime()); // convert gettime from date and assign it to your timestamp.
    }
```

Comment: constructing a Date with a String parameter is deprecated since Java 8

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to convert String Date to Epoc Timestamp.
Note : - Your input Date format should match with SimpleDateFormat.

```
String inputDateInString= "8/15/2017 12:00:00 AM";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss");

Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("inputDateInString");

Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());

System.out.println("Timestamp "+ timestamp.getTime());
```