# How to get the all value in between two specific value from array list in android?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a `arraylist` which is string type. In this `arraylist` i store some date like

```
 ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
    date.add("20-jan-2013 11:32:39 AM");
    date.add("21-jan-2013 11:32:39 AM");
    date.add("22-jan-2013 11:32:39 AM");
    date.add("23-jan-2013 11:32:39 AM");
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    date.add("29-jan-2013 11:32:39 AM");
```

More then 20 value in the array list. and my question is how i get the value(date) from `arrayList` in between two value(date) like from this date  `21-jan-2013 11:32:39 AM to 27-jan-2013 11:32:39 AM.`
Help me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
Date convertedDate = new Date();
ArrayList<String> filteredDate=new ArrayList<String>;
Iterator<String> iterator = lList.iterator();

for (String temp : lList) 
{
 try
    {
    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(temp);
     } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if((convertedDate.before(date2)) && (convertedDate.after(date1))) //here "date2" and "date1" must be converted to dateFormat
    {
      filteredDate.add(convertedDate); // You can use these filtered ArrayList
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean foundFirst = false;
for(String s : date) {
    if(!foundFirst) {
        if(s.equals(myFirstElement)) {
            foundFirst = true;
            result.add(s);
        }
    } else {
        result.add(s);
        if(s.equals(myLastElement) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somethink like this will work:

```
    ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();

    int begin=0, end=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < date.size(); i++){
        if(date.get(i).equals(myFirstDate)){
            begin = i;
        }
        if(date.get(i).equals(myLastDate)){
            end = i;
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> myDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < (end - begin); i++){
        myDates.add(date.get(i + begin));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

do something like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> filter(ArrayList<String> original, String startDate, String endDate) {
    TimeStamp start = ...; 
    TimeStamp end = ...;
```

here you need to get the timestamp of the string values, to see how this works take a look at this [question, and the provided answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742380/how-to-convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-java).

```
    ArrayList temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i= 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
       TimeStamp currentTimeStamp = timestamp of original.get(i)
       if (start < currentTimeStamp && stop > currentTimeStamp) {
           temp.add(original.get(i));
       }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

This should solve your problem