# Perform select of data from multiple tablea using JDBC template

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I need to perfom a select by date from my DB in my spring boot webapp. What I have so far is a list of sport competitions and there respective informations.

Problem : I can not figure out how my select query convert my String type (dateFrom = '2017-05-02' and dateTo = '2017-05-06') to date like '2017-02-12' in the **?**

Alos how to fill my RowMapper with more **then one date** in some competition which have more then one date.

**My data base schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE competition ( 
  competition_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  nom varchar(128) NOT NULL,
); 

CREATE TABLE date ( 
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  date_time timestamptz,
  competition_id integer REFERENCES competition (competition_id)
);
```

**Json data:**

```
{
    "id": "420",
    "name": "SOCCER",
    "dates": [
        "2016-05-12T03:00:00.000Z"
        "2016-05-12T04:00:00.000Z"
        "2016-05-12T05:00:00.000Z"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "220",
    "name": "BASKETBALL",
    "dates": [
        "2016-05-12T03:00:00.000Z"
        "2016-05-12T04:00:00.000Z"
    ]
}
```

**My competition Class:**

```
public class Competition{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String[] dates;
    // setters ... getters
}
```

**My RowMapper Class:**

```
public class RowMapper implements RowMapper
{
  public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Competition competition  = new Competition();
    competition.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    competition.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    competition. // How to fill dates
    return competition;
  }

}
```

**Function to select data :**

```
private static final String SELECT_STMT =
      " select * from competition INNER JOIN date ON
    + " competition.competition_id = date.competition_id"
    + " WHERE date(date.date_time) BETWEEN ? AND ?"
    ;  

public List<Competition> findByOptionsAll(String dateFrom, String dateTo ){

  List<Competition> competitions = jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_STMT, new 
     RowMapper(), dateFrom, dateTo);          

    return competitions ;
}
```

Comment: do you want to hold dates as a `String`or you want to use `Date`?  in Java app? In DB?

Comment: No, in DB date is timestampz, but I extract the date only with date(...). I still have trouble on replacing ? ? by the proper values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Date converting

Right now you have all dates as a `String` both in your DB and domain model. To convert strings to date you need a [date formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yy";
// parsing date; Note you should handle ParseException
java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).parse(dateAsString);
// converting date to string
String dateAsString = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).format(date);
```

Note that SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe so it's a good practice to have `static final String DATE_FORMAT` instead of `static final DateFormatter`

Converting date and time is tricky in some cases (what about time zone? java.util.Date vs joda.time vs LocalDate from Java 8) but out of scope. I suggest use LocalDate if possible just because it's a new way without old issues.

### Mapping

You have two entities in your DB (Competition and Date-of-competition) and only one class `Competition` in your domain model. Most probably, later you'll want to add additional info to the Date-of-competition (boolean finished, cancelled, Score etc) so it's a good idea to create `CompetitionInstance` class right now.

Since you have One-to-Many relationship you have to write some additional stuff to map objects. Normally that's what an ORM like Hibernate do istead of you. First, add a 'GROUP BY competition_id' in your sql statement.
Then use RowSetExtractor instead of RowMapper as described [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-jdbc-rowmapper-vs-resultsetextractor):

```
private static final class CompetitionMapExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor<List<Competition>> {
@Override
public List<Competition> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
  List<Competition> result = new ArrayList<>(rs.getCount());
  int previousCompetitionId = NEVER_EXIST; // normally -1 is good enough
  while (rs.next()) {
     // we have some dates with the same competition_id 
     // dates are grouped thanks to GROUP BY clause        
     if ( rs.getInt("id") != previousCompetitionId) {
       Competition currentCompetition = new Competition(rs.getInt("id"),
                     rs.getString("name");
       /* I prefer constructor initializers "o = new O(propertyValue)"
        instead of snippet "o = new O(); o.setProperty(value)"
       */
       result.add(currentCompetition);
       previousCompetitionId = currentCompetition.getid();
     } else {
       currentCompetition.addDate(new CompetitionInstance(rs.getString("date")));
     }
  }
  return result;
}
```

I suppose `Competition` has method `public void addDate(String date)` which simply add a new CompetitionInstance to a list.

### Update:

1.
column name in DB and in MapExtractor is different. I prefer to change the query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, d.date_time as date
from competition c 
INNER JOIN date d ON c.competition_id = d.competition_id
WHERE date(d.date_time) BETWEEN ? AND ?"
```

2. I can't reproduce issues you have with date. Most probably you mixed up `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` - this is a common mistake. There are many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742380/how-to-convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-java) already, probably you could find [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974973/java-timestamp-how-can-i-create-a-timestamp-with-the-date-23-09-2007) of [them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+timestamp+date) useful.

Comment: I'm no using Hibernate, but this code  List<Competition> competitions = jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_STMT, new RowMapper(), dateFrom, dateTo); still cause me errors() (index column hout of limit). when I add the two parameters.

Comment: @DavidEdgar It's because in DB you have column 'timestamptz' and in my code it called 'date'. The better way is to change SELECT query