# convert date time string to unix timestamp

Tags: java, date, time, java-7, jodatime

I have a string for date time coming as like this without any spaces in between them:

```
TueDec2618:47:09UTC2017
```

Is there any way to convert this to unix timestamps? The date time string will always be in that format.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: look at this : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742380/how-to-convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-java/2742398](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742380/how-to-convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-java/2742398)

Comment: What's the time in this string?

Comment: Don't follow the advice to use `SimpleDateFormat`, if you need to parse a string to date and time use `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: @ernest_k my interpretation of that string is `2017-12-26 18:47:09 UTC`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes thats what the above time is.

Comment: This should work: `ZonedDateTime.parse("TueDec2618:47:09UTC2017", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEMMMddHH:mm:sszyyyy"))`. It produces `2017-12-26T18:47:09Z[UTC]`

Comment: I am still on Java 7 btw so can't use ZonedDataTime and DateTimeFormatter but I can use joda library.

Comment: @Skrelp Even on Java 7 please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Java 7 when you add [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project. Better than and a successor of Joda-Time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTen Backport

The [comment by ernest_k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068965/convert-date-time-string-to-unix-timestamp#comment96885647_55068965) is well thought out and solves your issue:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEMMMddHH:mm:sszyyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateTimeString = "TueDec2618:47:09UTC2017";
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
    long unixTimestamp = dateTime.toEpochSecond();
    System.out.println("Parsed date-time " + dateTime + " Unix timestamp " + unixTimestamp);
```

The output from running on ThreeTen Backport 1.3.6, tested on Java 1.7.0_79, is:

> Parsed date-time 2017-12-26T18:47:09Z[Zulu] Unix timestamp 1514314029

### Question: How can I use ZonedDateTime and DateTimeFormatter on Java 7?

> I am still on Java 7 btw so can't use `ZonedDataTime` and
>   `DateTimeFormatter` but I can use joda library.

Indeed you can. java.time just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

While Joda-Time would be another nice solution, I believe that you should prefer the ThreeTen Backport over Joda-Time (though opinions differ). The Joda-Time home page advises:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to `java.time` (JSR-310).

So java.time seems to be the future-proof solution.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Joda-Time home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)