# Java SQL subtract an hour from date

Tags: java, sql, date, timestamp

I need a `java.sql.Timestamp` value corresponding to one hour ago.  I have a few date related things happening here so it's important that the current time is sampled only once and the rest of the code uses that same time.  As far as setting a `Timestamp` based on current time in ms.

Manipulating the `Calendar` object seems really klunky since I have to do things like add and subtract time to the calendar, which modifies it, so then I would have the lovely pleasure of either cloning myself a copy first or toggling its value around.

Comment: Why did you tag this with SQL? Do you want a solution in Java or a solution on how to do it with SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply subtract an hour off of the current time in milliseconds when making your timestamp (1 hour = 60 * 60 * 1000 ms)

```
Timestamp oneHourAgo = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - (60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
mySqlTimestamp.toInstant()
              .minus( Duration.ofHours( 1 ) )
```

## Avoid old date-time classes

The java.sql types are intended only for exchanging data with a database. Do not use these for business logic.

The troublesome old date-time classes are now supplanted by the java.time classes. The java.time equivalent of [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). You can even convert to/from via new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = mySqlTimestamp.toInstant();
```

You can then subtract an hour represented by a `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 1 );
Instant hourPrior = instant.minus( d );
```

Note that these classes follow [Immutable Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern. Rather than modifying (“mutating”) parts of the values in the object, a new object is instantiated based on the values of the original. So no problem with [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) discussed in another answer. And automatically [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Comment: Just came across this answer.  My only concern/question is what is mySqlTimeStamp?

Comment: @MarkII `mySqlTimestamp` is a fictional placeholder for your name of your instance of `java.sql.Timestamp` mentioned in the prior paragraph. The lowercase `m` is a convention telling you it is an instance rather than a class, and `my…` is a common convention for naming variables in simplistic example code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like this one:

```
Timestamp subtractOneHour(Timestamp stamp)
{
    long current = stamp.getTime();
    long substracted = current - 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return new Timestamp(substracted);
}
```

Comment: Slightly dangerous, as the method signature implies that it has no side effects.  I'd recommend cloning the timestamp in any case, and probably actually spell out 'subtract'.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread: [Java Timestamp - How can I create a Timestamp with the date 23/09/2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974973/java-timestamp-how-can-i-create-a-timestamp-with-the-date-23-09-2007)

> it's important that the current time is sampled only once and the
>   rest of the code uses that same time.

I recommend assigning the time to a variable, and then re-using the same variable..

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options besides messing around with a `Calendar` object -

1. Use the [Apache Date Utilities](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html), which will essentially mess around with a `Calendar` (if necessary) for you, but returns a new `Date` object (so, threadsafe).
2. Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for dealing with date/time, which is usually considered a better library overall.