# How to use Timestamp constructor

Tags: java, timestamp, deprecated, default-constructor

I want to use the default constructor for the **Timestamp** class in Java but Eclipse indicates that it is **deprecated**. This is the constructor:

`Timestamp myDate = new Timestamp(2014, 3, 24, 0, 0, 0 ,0);`

Eclipse recommends using `Timestamp(long time)` default constructor but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) for current time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about the next [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)?

```
int myYear = 2014;
int myMonth = 3;
int myDay = 24;
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d 00:00:00", 
                                                myYear, myMonth, myDay));
```

Using [JSR 310: Date and Time API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) (introduced in the Java SE 8 [release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html)):

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(
        java.time.LocalDate.of(myYear, myMonth, myDay).atStartOfDay()
);
```

Comment: I have the `int` variables `myYear`, `myMonth` and `myDay`. How can I use them here:
`Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf("myYear-myMonth-myDay 00:00:00");`

Comment: @robysottini you could also set the variables in the `Calendar` properties as well and generate your `Date` object instead...

Answer (score 3):

Create a `java.util.Date` instance (not to be confused with `java.sql.Date`) and pass its time in milliseconds as argument to the `Timestamp`. Here's an example:

```
Timestamp now = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```

There are other ways to create a `java.util.Date` object instance:

- Using `Calendar`:

  ```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
  Date today = calendar.getTime();
  Timestamp now = new Timestamp(today.getTime());
  ```
- Using `DateFormat` or it's child class `SimpleDateFormat`.

  ```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  Date date = sdf.parse("2014/3/24");
  Timestamp today = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974973/java-timestamp-how-can-i-create-a-timestamp-with-the-date-23-09-2007), you can parse it using the DateFormat class:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("23/09/2007");
long time = date.getTime();
new Timestamp(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up Calendar for specific date, then get time in millisecond are use it in constructor of Timestamp:

```
new Timestamp(new GregorianCalendar(2014, 3, 24).getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GregorianCalendar class

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second);
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

If you have a string in the below format, then you can also do:

```
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2014-01-01 00:00:00");
```

Comment: Use `Calendar.getInstance` instead of working directly with `GregorianCalendar`.