# Convert Date to Timestamp

Tags: java, date, timestamp

How to convert Date to Timestamp in java?

This line give me the following error:
"The constructor Timpestamp(Date) is undefined"

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(Date);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974973/java-timestamp-how-can-i-create-a-timestamp-with-the-date-23-09-2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public Timestamp convertDateToTimestamp(Date date) {
    Timestamp timestamp = null;
    if (date != null) {
        timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }
    return timestamp;
}
```

Comment: How about explaining to OP what was wrong with their attempt?  Copy and pasting is not a very useful teaching tool

Comment: @demongolem You did something worse putting a link to an answer that has a bad url

Comment: This is a duplicate which has been answered multiple times.  We do not need it answered yet again so you can get your precious reputation.

Answer (score 1):

`Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());`

or

`Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());`