# Calculate time asked by a server from day date

Tags: android, objective-c, date, time

I am trying to make a request to a server with a string parameter called time which is something like "1407841229".

Now, I noticed that this number is probably equal to the amount of seconds since 1/1/1970, 00:00:01.
Here's my calculus : 1407841229 / (60*60*24*365,25) = 44,6117964928, which is roughly 44 years, 7 months, 11 days and a few hours.

I would like to calculate this number from the date given by system clock.

Do you think it could be possible ? I intend to use this in a mobile app written for iPhone (Objective-C) and Android (Java), so the method would have to be universal.

EDIT : I managed to get the number from the server with another request. It is a lot easier and probably safer if I was to write down the algorithm in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for timestamp. From Wikipedia you get:

> A Timestamp, Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing
>   points in time, defined as the number of seconds elapsed since
>   midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not
>   counting leap seconds. It is widely used not only on Unix-like
>   operating systems but also in many other computing systems. It is
>   neither a linear representation of time nor a true representation of
>   UTC (though it is frequently mistaken for both) as the times it
>   represents are UTC but it has no way of representing UTC leap seconds
>   (e.g. 1998-12-31 23:59:60).

Every programing language should probably have its own conversion functions: time -> date and date -> time. Here on stackoverflow you can find a similar question right answered:

[Java Timestamp - How can I create a Timestamp with the date 23/09/2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974973/java-timestamp-how-can-i-create-a-timestamp-with-the-date-23-09-2007)

Comment: Thanks, I had the feeling they were common in programming, but I didn't know about timestamps. Even though I probably found a better way to get what I want, I will definitely read about them.