# How can we store the timestamp into the list when log4j messages are stored into the list and fetched into a swt table created

Tags: java, list, log4j, swt

I also need to store the time stamp inside the list when the log message is pushed into the list.So how can we get the timestamp  and push into the list.I am pushing the logs into the list as follows

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender;
//import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class Listappender extends RollingFileAppender {

    private List<LoggingEvent> events = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();
    static List<String> clone = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void doAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
        //System.out.println("hi....");
        //events.clear();
        events.add(event);
        super.doAppend(event);
        clone.clear();

        clone.add((String) event.getMessage());

        //getEvents();

        /*
        for (int j = 0; j < events.size(); j++){

            System.out.println(events.get(j));
            System.out.println(j);
        }*/

    }



    public List<String> getEntries()
    {
        return clone;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

See how to create timestamp [Java Timestamp - How can I create a Timestamp with the date 23/09/2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974973/java-timestamp-how-can-i-create-a-timestamp-with-the-date-23-09-2007)

And you can simply do this

```
    clone.add(timestamp.toString() + event.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the `LoggingEvent` s in a list. You don't have to get the message and save it in a different list. The `LoggingEvent` has a `public final long getTimeStamp()` method to supply the time. Try using this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class ListAppender extends RollingFileAppender {

    private final List<LoggingEvent> events = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void doAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
        events.add(event);
        super.doAppend(event);
    }

    public synchronized List<LoggingEvent> getLoggingEvents() {
        List<LoggingEvent> clone = new ArrayList<>(events);
        events.clear();
        return clone;
    }

}
```